# How do you turn a user into staff?

Tags: python, django

Using a view i want to turn a user into staff, how do i do it. using is_staff just gives me if the user is staff or not.

```
def createAdmin(request,member_id):
    admin_group= Group.objects.get(name='admin')
    member = get_object_or_404(Member,pk=member_id)
    user = User.objects.get(member = member)
    admin_group.user_set.add(user)
    user.staff=True
    user.save()
```

This is the code i use to make that user a admin but i don't know how i could give him staff status. user.staff doesn't work.

Comment: What does staff mean to you that isn't covered by the [`is_staff`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.is_staff) boolean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set the `is_staff` field, so:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def createAdmin(request,member_id):
    admin_group= get_object_or_404(Group, name='admin')
    member = get_object_or_404(Member,pk=member_id)
    user = get_object_or_404(User, member=member)
    admin_group.user_set.add(user)
    user.is_staff = True
    user.save()
```

You should do this only in case of a POST request, since a GET request is *not* supposed to have side effects. In order to make it a *super user* as well, you can set the `.is_superuser`:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def createAdmin(request,member_id):
    admin_group= get_object_or_404(Group, name='admin')
    member = get_object_or_404(Member,pk=member_id)
    user = get_object_or_404(User, member=member)
    admin_group.user_set.add(user)
    user.is_staff = True
    user.is_superuser = True
    user.save()
```

---

> **Note**: You can limit views to POST requests with the
> [**`@require_POST`** decorator [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/decorators/#django.views.decorators.http.require_POST).

Comment: "using is_staff just gives me if the user is staff or not." - not sure what the op means though

Comment: @Sayse: you should *set* the `.is_staff` field.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem has given you an answer, use `user.is_staff=True` instead of `user.staff=True`

Comment: I didn't use staff.save() when i was using user.is_staff so it never actually changed it. so i was checking using print(). Thats what i meant. Thank you for the answer its correct.